# How can I get the elder scroll dialogue from the orc in the college?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Its been two days since I went with Parthurnax and Arngeir and no dialogue option appears from Urag at the college.
I can't seem to get the option to be able to go look for the scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to talk to the Orc, instead, go out of the Collegs, go down the cliffs, and then keep going north until you find a place called Septimus Signus's Outpost. There inside talk to the guy in robes and he'll give you a quest to find the Elder Scroll.